Getting response from blocked website with urllib
Im writing discord bot with urllib. While doing is-online (website) command im stuck with problem - in Russia there is certain websites are blocked (for example - discord.com , discord.gg etc.)
Is there any way to get real response from website? Becouse discord.com is online, but bc of block code showing what it's offline.
Im tried to setup proxy, but with proxy, it won't connect to ANY website
Tried to search on other resources, even ask AI - nothing
